# Control the transition between two viewControllers

Tags: iphone

I am new to objective-c and have recently started making iOS applications in Xcode. I was making a **login** application that has two view controllers. It looks like this:  http://imgur.com/W3nxMEG

Now my issue is that I was the app to go to second ViewController only if:
1) Text fields are filled
2) Passwords match

that's the code that I've written. I couldnt find any command that controls the transition between the viewControlled based on the certain constraints:

```
(IBAction)loginButton:(id)sender {

BOOL passMatch, emptyUser, emptyPass, emptyrePass;

passMatch = [password isEqualToString:reEnter];

emptyUser = [username isEqualToString:@""];

emptyPass = [password isEqualToString:@""];

emptyrePass = [reEnter isEqualToString:@""];


if (emptyPass || emptyUser || emptyrePass){

    UIAlertView *error=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Ooops!" message:@"You must complete all the fields " delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [error show];

}

else{

    passMatch = [password isEqualToString:reEnter];

    if (passMatch){


       UIAlertView *pass=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success!" message:@"Passwords match " delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [pass show];

    } else{

        UIAlertView *error=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Ooops!" message:@"Passwords dont match " delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [error show];
    }
}
```

---

Shall be thankful if anyone can help me solve this

Comment: Please for edit the format of your code its kinda hard to read.. :)

Answer (score 0):

First make sure your `UITextField` and `UIButton` from your storyBoard are hooked with a property in `LoginViewController.h`

It'll look like this:

> LoginViewController.h

```
@interface LoginViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *password;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *username;

// and so on..

// for your button
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *loginButton;

@end
```

> LoginViewController.m

```
@implementation LoginViewController


-(IBAction)loginButton:(id)sender 
{

    // you can enable/disable your button here also, by:
    // UIButton *senderButton = (UIButton *)sender;
    // senderButton.enabled = YES/NO;

    // i'm just using .length because i trust numbers more that the @""
    NSString *errorMessage;

if (self.username.text.length == 0)
    errorMessage = @"username is required";

else if (self.password.text.length == 0)
    errorMessage = @"password is required";

else if (self.reEnter.text.length == 0)
    errorMessage = @"please confirm your password";

else if (self.password.text.length == 0 || self.username.text.length == 0 || self.reEnter.text.length == 0)
    errorMessage = @"You must complete all the fields";

if (errorMessage.length > 0)
{
    UIAlertView *error=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Ooops!" message:errorMessage delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [error show];
}
else
{
    if ([self.username.text isEqual: @"youUsername"] && [self.password.text isEqual: @"youPassword"] && [self.password.text isEqual: self.reEnter.text])
    {
        UIAlertView *pass=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success!" message:@"Login successful" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [pass show];

        //presentYourSecondViewController         
        //[self presentViewController:(UIViewController) animated:(BOOL) completion:nil];
        //[self.navigationController pushViewController:(UIViewController)animated:(BOOL)];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *error=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Ooops!" message:@"Login failed" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [error show];
    }
}


    /* Your code...


    BOOL passMatch, emptyUser, emptyPass, emptyrePass;

    passMatch = [password isEqualToString:reEnter];

    emptyUser = [username isEqualToString:@""];

    emptyPass = [password isEqualToString:@""];

    emptyrePass = [reEnter isEqualToString:@""];

    if (emptyPass || emptyUser || emptyrePass){

        UIAlertView *error=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Ooops!" message:@"You must complete all the fields " delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [error show];

    }

    else
    {

        passMatch = [password isEqualToString:reEnter];

        if (passMatch){

            UIAlertView *pass=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success!" message:@"Passwords match " delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [pass show];

        } else{

            UIAlertView *error=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Ooops!" message:@"Passwords dont match " delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [error show];
        }
    }
    */
}

@end
```

There is nothing wrong with your condition i just over did it i guess.. Anyway hope i've help you Happy coding cheers..

Comment: Alright, I will try your code tomorrow but for now can you tell me a way to disable/enable a button? Like I just want the button to take me to second viewController if the fields are entered & passwords match.
 In my case it's a 'login' button as you can see in a picture.

Comment: assuming your button is hooked from storyboard, its saomething like.. self.yourbutton.enabled = NO/YES; f

Comment: I should write this command in the loginButton method, right? (loginButton is the button that upon being pressed takes me to second viewController).

Comment: Yes.. Or make a new method and call it, just to make things clearer.. :)

Comment: I am getting error: "Property 'loginButton' not found on object of type viewController"
when I am using this "self.loginButton.enabled = YES;" in loginButton method.

Comment: you need to hooked the button from storyboard with the name `loginButton `

Comment: Are you sure you hooked the loginButton to a property like above? `@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *loginButton;`

Comment: No I used it as an action, not as an outlet.

- (IBAction)loginButton:(id)sender;

Comment: you must hooked it as `IBOutlet` also, for the `self.loginButton.enable` to work..

Comment: OK so I made a pointer namely modButton and hooked it with the loginButton in my storyboard. I used [self.modButton setEnabled:NO] in my code but again it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: This is the code that I used:

http://imgur.com/01Y6X6U

does it look right to you now?

Comment: Still taking me to next view controller when none of the fields are filled :/

Comment: Where are you call presentViewController or pushViewController? can you post your code for that?

Comment: You mean the sague action? Its modal (deprecated)